# SQL query to count secondary keys

Tags: sql, key

For a given table, if I count the keys (other then the primary key) which are having NOT NULL and UNIQUE, both the constraints, will that give me count of secondary keys for that table?

If not, how to get count of secondary keys for a table by using SQL query?

Comment: Can you add an example to illustrate what you asking?

Comment: No there may be columns where they are not part of any index yet they aren ot null

Comment: Primary key and secondary keys make up candidate keys. Since, as per my understanding, candidate keys need to be unique and not null, shouldn't that help us to get count of secondary keys?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. As you said in your own comment, it gives you candidate keys (provided there are constraints / indexes on them).

Imagine a country table. You could use the natural key, i.e. the country name, as its primary key. Then you would have a primary key and no other non null unique index. Okay so far.

Now you add an id to your country table. No matter if you decide to use this as the primary key or stay with the natural key, you will have one primary key and one non null unique index. So you've found your secondary key.

However, if for some reason someone adds another index containing both the country name and the id, then you'd get another non null unique index. However, I wouldn't consider this another secondary key. It's only another index to speed up certain lookups.

So yes, you can look for non null unique indexes to find secondary keys, but you are not done with it. You must also check if a thus found index is just a combination of other non null unique indexes. Get rid of these and that should be it.

Comment: Hello, is there sql query to calculate number of primary and secondary keys? I dont want to count foreign keys.. only primary and secondary keys.... is this possible?